# jQuery animation not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, jquery-animate

I'm making a website for my portfolio however my animation is not working in FireFox. I've trawled through my CSS and script and I can't find any errors that could be causing issues. My code works on all other browsers except FireFox. The animation is meant to move the overlay td's out diagonally however in FireFox they just sit there and then fadeout.
Below are my 2 animation functions and heres a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aw555000/JzRLN/).

```
$('.overlay').click(overlaymove);
$('#logo').click(overlayreturn);

function overlaymove() {
    $('.tl').animate({
        "right": "265px",
            "bottom": "265px"
    }, 1500);
    $('.tr').animate({
        "left": "265px",
            "bottom": "265px"
    }, 1500);
    $('.bl').animate({
        "right": "265px",
            "top": "265px"
    }, 1500);
    $('.br').animate({
        "left": "265px",
            "top": "265px"
    }, 1500);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".overlay").hide();
    }, 1500);
}

function overlayreturn() {
    $('.overlay').show();
    $('.tl').delay(500).animate({
        "right": "0px",
            "bottom": "0px"
    }, 1500);
    $('.tr').delay(500).animate({
        "left": "0px",
            "bottom": "0px"
    }, 1500);
    $('.bl').delay(500).animate({
        "right": "0px",
            "top": "0px"
    }, 1500);
    $('.br').delay(500).animate({
        "left": "0px",
            "top": "0px"
    }, 1500);
    $('.content').fadeOut(1000);
}
```

Please help me find a solution as this is annoying. I have had a look around at similar topic but they either don't provide an answer of the answer is to do with background positioning which I do not use.

Comment: I've had problems in the past with firefox, animations, and tables.  It seemed to me like the problem was specifically around the hiding and showing functions in jquery.  Instead of trying to find a workaround for this, I would really recommend changing this from being a tabular structure to being a bunch of DIVs.  I'm not always one to poo-poo using tables, but it does seem like this is a situation that would be a lot better suited for DIVs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gecko/Firefox does not support relative positioning of table cells. So, with your current markup, it is simply not possible to make this work. Use positioned DIVs instead and it'll work fine.

Comment: Changed td's to divs and repositioned them, now all works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firefox doesn't allow you to position table cells relatively, or more accurately, elements which are `display: table-cell`.  One workaround would be to set your `td` elements to some other `display` value such as `inline-block`:

http://jsfiddle.net/JzRLN/4/

Though this will likely mess up some other formatting of the page.  Really, a table just isn't the best idea for this usage.